# Reading replies from outlook messenger using window service

Tags: email, outlook

I have a window service that reads the reply of mail and classify them based on the hidden fields into the replied email body. But while replying from outlook messenger or any other web servers other than the browsers, the hidden fields are not received into the email body of replied mail. I want the solution that why the hidden fields are not sent back to my email body while replying from outlook messenger or any other web email servers other than browser. Need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code do you have now?

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev, I am having C# code, that fetch and parse entire email body using string manipulation. but when i fetch email body and parse it, the hidden fields are not present. just need to know the reason why the hidden fields are not sent back. Same thing work if i reply email from browser.

Comment: What code exactly do you use? User properties can be vanished on the recipient's side if they are not defined on the delivery store.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what code you use at the moment in a service, but Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

You may consider using a low-level API on which Outlook is based - Extended MAPI or any other third-party wrappers around that API (for example, Redemption). In case if you deal only with Exchange servers consider using the [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: I think i have to find alternative for client side. Thanks